# Disk read error after installing Ubuntu on second HDD

Tags: boot, grub2, partitioning, windows-7

I have two slots for HDD in my notebook (HP Pavilion dv7 6b30ew). Firstly I had only one HDD in the Slot 1 with Windows 7 installed on it. Currently I bought second HDD, put it into Slot 2 and installed Ubuntu 16.04. But during installation it says that it cannot install bootloader on my HDD with Windows. I tried to install bootloader on HDD with Ubuntu but it didn't work - after restart only Windows was booted. Finally I cleared HDD with Ubuntu.

My second idea is swap disks. As I thought I did and now HDD with Windows is in the Slot 2 and empty HDD is in the Slot 2. I installed Ubuntu on empty disk and everything works like a dream with one exception - when notebook is turned on it displays list with Ubuntu and Windows, when I choose Ubuntu it works, but if I select Windows it shows me black screen with error "A disk read error occurred".

What is interesting, when I put HDD with Windows in Slot 1 it again start working. But of course I cannot boot Ubuntu.

How can I fix this? I spend three days trying install Ubuntu in different combination (different slots, with and without HDD with Windows, etc.) but without results.

Result of executing `sudo parted -l` in `Try Ubuntu without installing`. I hope it helps solve my problem.

```
Model: ATA HGST HTS721010A9 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 1000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system     Flags
 1      1049kB  4096MB  4095MB  primary  linux-swap(v1)
 2      4096MB  1000GB  996GB   primary  ext4            boot


Model: ATA Hitachi HTS54757 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 750GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
 1      32,3kB  1049kB  1016kB  primary
 2      1049kB  106MB   105MB   primary  ntfs         boot
 3      106MB   107GB   107GB   primary  ntfs
 4      107GB   750GB   643GB   primary  ntfs
```

Comment: Is Windows installed in legacy-mode and you installed Ubuntu in UEFI-mode?

Comment: How can I check this?

Comment: In this [manual](http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c03043778) on page 105 and following
is explained how to enter the Bios-setup-utility. You have to use arrow-keys and enter-key
then. Look in the `System Configuration`-tab for `Boot Options`, choose this with arrow-keys
and hit enter. From here you have to look yourself, I couldn't find more details on the net.
I am sure you can change the boot-order there. Try out please...

Answer (score 0):

SO, this looks fine, both drives have msdos-partition-table.
Put your Windows-drive in slot 1, as I understand you will then be able to boot directly to Windows without getting to Grub-menu, check that first please.

The Ubuntu-drive put in the other slot.

Now reinstall Ubuntu (make sure to boot the installer in legacy-mode) to the Ubuntu-drive. Choose `Something else`. You can use the existing partitions.

During partitioning please double-check the drive-letter of the Ubuntu-drive, it is either `sda` or `sdb`. You will need this drive-letter of the Ubuntu-drive when it is going to install Grub.

You will be prompted where to install Grub. Install Grub in the MBR of the Ubuntu-drive so your answer is either `sda` or `sdb`, you have checked the drive-letter in the step before. Do NOT install Grub to a partition (something like `sda1` or `sdb2`), this will not be bootable.

When installation is finished and you reboot, enter BIOS-setup and change the boot-order to Ubuntu-drive in first place, so when you boot, you will boot to Grub. You will be able now to choose Windows or Ubuntu, both options will work.

You will be also able to boot to Windows directly as we didn't overwrite the Windows-boot-loader in the MBR of the Windows-drive, you just would need to change the boot-order in BIOS-setup (helpful when Grub fails for whatever reason)...

EDIT:

What a surprise!

```
Only hard drive bay 1 supports bootable hard drives.
```

I found this in [HP-Support](http://support.hp.com/us-en/product/HP-Pavilion-dv7-Entertainment-Notebook-PC-series/5145684/model/5198274/document/c01443463/)
-website for your laptop-model.
You can not boot from the drive in slot2. You can use the drive only as a data-storage.

If you want to dual-boot Ubuntu with Windows on your machine, you will have to install Ubuntu on the Windows-drive in slot1. You would need to resize your Windows-partition to make space for Ubuntu. Use windows-tools for resizeing Windows-partitions. Backup first.

You can install Ubuntu in logical partitions, you don't need to install Ubuntu in a primary partition. 40 GB for Ubuntu are comfortable, you can give more space, it's almost up to you.

You should be able to mount partitions on the second drive to Ubunutu and use them as data-storage for Ubuntu.
Also good to have a extra NTFS-partition where you can share data with Windows and Ubuntu, better than to mount the Windows-system-partition
to Ubuntu.

Comment: I've added result of `sudo parted -l` in my question. Hope it helps.

Comment: I just did as you wrote, but it turns out that my BIOS doesn't support booting from the second drive. Can only boot from the first drive. I updated the BIOS to the latest version, but it did not help.

Comment: Sorry. I was offline last time because I'm trying to reinstall my stupid Windows. It's really problematic to do it, much easier would be installing one of cracked version instead of original one!

Comment: But the thing, I made backup and formatted both drives. Then I installed Windows on first drive and I have two partitions for it - `sda1` (105MB for boot), `sda2` (707GB for Windows). Additionally I have 40GB free space for Ubuntu on `sda` and entire `sdab` drive (1TB). And I have problem how to organize this space - partitioning and mount points (`/`, `/boot`, `/home`, `/tmp`, `/usr`, `/var`, `/srv`, `/opt`, `/usr/local`). Further I think I will manage - from a few years I use Mac OS.

Comment: You don't need that much partitions. you need one swap-partition and you need the `/`-partition. To have the other directories in their own partitions is optional and i wouldn't recommend that for you. If you want you may create one more partition for `/home` on the second drive. Mountpoint for `/`-partition is `/`, mountpoint for `/home`-partition is `/home`.

Comment: Then, `/home` should be mounted on `sdb` and `/` should be mounted on `sda3`? Or maybe only `/boot` have to be on `sda3`? Basically I want to have as much as possible on `sdb`.

Comment: I would put the `/`-partition on sda and `/home`-partition on sdb, also the swap-partition on sdb. I would not create a separate `/boot`-partition. It is better to keep it simple...